# Android background picture's effect on performance

Tags: android, performance, android-imageview, textview

I'm a beginner in android development.
I have a text view which uses this logic to animate text:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){    
                textLayout.SetText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++).toString());                  
                if(mIndex<=mLength) {    
                    if(mIndex<mLength)
                        if (mText.charAt(mIndex) == ' '){
                            mIndex++;
                        }
                    mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);
                }
}
```

mDelay is set to 50ms

It's works fine when background image's resolution is small (1080x750), but much slower with 1920x1080.
What is the connection between image and Handler?
Is it because activity redraws imageView each time i call setText? 
What is the best practice for high-resolution pictures?

Thanks.

Comment: use .svg for adding image or use different size with drawable hdpi , mdpi , xhdpi , xxhdpi. @IgorXY